# how do I use sed to delete lines with single digit instead of double

Tags: sed

I have this line.

```
sed -i '/Total number 1/d' /tmp/test.txt
```

This will delete lines,

```
Total number 1
```

but it also deletes,

```
Total number 11

Total number 12

Total number 13
```

how do I set it to delete single digit only?

Answer (score 3):

Add a dollar sign to the end `sed -i '/Total number 1$/d' /tmp/test.txt`

Also, if you want to delete any single digit, replace 1: `sed -i '/Total number [0-9]$/d' /tmp/test.txt`

Finally, if the number isn't necessarily at the end of the line, you could also have the pattern end when either the end of line or a non-digit is found: `sed -i -E '/Total number [0-9]($|[^0-9])/d' /tmp/test.txt`

Comment: An "end-of-word" marker should work too: `/Total number [0-9]\>/d`

Answer (score 1):

The precise and generic solution would be:

```
sed '/\b[[:digit:]]\b/d'
```

`\b` stands for a [*word boundary*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Pass the `-i` option once you made sure that the above command works for *you* since it would effectively change your input files.